# Focus on div without click in React to enable keyboard navigation on a module

Tags: reactjs, focus

I am coding an image gallery from scratch in React, when clicking on an image, a modal pops up (separate component from my gallery component). I want to **navigate between the pictures with left and right arrow**, not just with the added arrows on the screen (onclick) but at the moment it only focuses on the modal when I click on it once, then I can navigate with the keyboard too (onKeyDown).

I have added tabIndex="0" to my div, but I still need to click on the div once to focus on it.

```
<div tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={(event) => this.onKeyNavigation(event, ImageUrl, currentIndex, ImageUrls)}>
```

---

```
onKeyNavigation = (event, ImageUrl, currentIndex, ImageUrls) => {

if ((event.keyCode) === 39) {
    this.props.loadNext(ImageUrl, currentIndex, ImageUrls)
  }
  else if ((event.keyCode) === 37) {
    this.props.loadPrevious(ImageUrl, currentIndex, ImageUrls)
  }
  else if ((event.keyCode) === 27) {
    this.props.onClose()
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to fire a `focus()` event on the `<div>` you want to have focus after it has rendered.

The easiest way to do this is to use React's built-in lifecycle methods. First, create a ref for the element you want to have focus (in this case, the div listening for keyDown events). Then, you can call `focus()` on that node in your component's `componentDidMount()` method:

```
class ImageGallery extends React.Component {
    construtor(){
        super();

        // Create the ref in the constructor
        this.focusRef = React.createRef();
    }

    /* your other methods here */

    componentDidMount(){
        // Focus on the rendered div using the DOM focus() method
        this.focusRef.focus();
    }

    render(){
        // Set the ref in your render() method
        return(<div ref={this.focusRef} onKeyDown={this.handle}></div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error on the `componentDidMount` method. this.focusRef.focus is not a function

Comment: You'll need to investigate to make sure the ref is getting set properly. Different versions of React handle this differently; you may need to set it as a function on the element (i.e. `ref={div => this.focusRef = div}` but the main idea still holds - you need to set focus on the element after render, and you can use the DOM node method `focus()` to do that.

Comment: I have React 16.6.1. I have gone through the documentation here: [link] https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html
I have also tried it with `componentDidMount() {
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }` I cannot seem to figure it out how to set the ref properly.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was:

`componentDidUpdate(){
  this.focusRef.current.focus();
  }`

Answer (score 0):

dcastrodale your answer helped me a lot, but for some reason this would not work until I placed the ref in the componentDidMount() inside of a setTimeout().  This is what I did to focus on a specific div when the page loaded.

```
//This line was added in the constructor().
this.drumMachineAndOuterControllerRef = React.createRef();

//This is how my componentDidMount() looks like.
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.drumMachineAndOuterControllerRef.current.focus();
  }, 5);
}

//This is the div that is put in focus after the page loads.
<div id="drum-machine-and-outer-controller" tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={this.keyboardPress} ref={this.drumMachineAndOuterControllerRef}>
```

This works great for me and I could even press the button elements with the keyboard without the mouse pointer ever entering the browser window.

Thanks again dcastrodale!  Your answer guided me in the right direction.